# Creating a custom list/dictionary of BoundFields for a django Form  (emulating form.hidden_fields)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

Okay, I have a somewhat complicated form with a lot of complicated business logic, and as a result I'm actually generating fields on the fly when the form is created. I need to be able to access the fields in the template but of course since they're generated I can't just do something like `{{ form.fieldname }}` because in this case `fieldname` is actually made from a variable.

I tried something like this in the form:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # initialization code is here, so let's just skip that
    self.items = kwargs.pop("items", [])
    self.my_fields = []
    for item in self.items:
        self.fields['item_%d' % item.pk]=forms.CharField(required=True, label=item.name)
        self.my_fields.append(self.fields['item_%d' % item.pk])
```

However, in the template, when I try this:

```
{% for field in self.my_fields %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get something like `<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x2b08aeb45810>`

Is there a way to do this so I can get the actual rendered field?

## Update

Looks like rendered fields have a type `django.forms.forms.BoundField` and are created when `__getitem__` is called on the `field` object. Basically, I guess I need some way to create something that behaves like `hidden_fields` only contains my fields instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. In order to make sure `__getitem__` was triggered, I needed to set the fields like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # initialization code is here, so let's just skip that
    self.items = kwargs.pop("items", [])
    self.my_fields = []
    for item in self.items:
        self.fields['item_%d' % item.pk]=forms.CharField(required=True, label=item.name)
        self.my_fields.append(self['item_%d' % item.pk])
```